# HH:MM:SS (with AM/PM) 12 Hour Timestamp for Bash Prompt

Tags: bash, date, prompt

I'm trying to add a timestamp to the beginning of my bash prompt in the format of a 12 hour HH:MM:SS AM/PM clock, and as of now, I've had no luck. Here's a couple things I've tried.

I've tried `date +%r` but that only updates each time my `~/.bashrc` is reloaded.

I've tried `\D{%T}` but that displays 24-hour time.

I've tried `\@` but that only displays HH:MM AM/PM.

I've tried `\t` but that displays 24-hour time.

I've tried `\T` but that does not show AM/PM.

Am I missing something, or is there some way to do this?

Comment: Does `\D{%r}` do what you want?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes! Thank you! I really should have tried that based on what I just said eh?

Comment: `\@` suits me better, thanks for documenting that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\D{%r}` displays 12 hour time in the HH:MM:SS AM/PM format.

Comment: greate,where do you find it?

Comment: In my opinion it would be nice if they removed the misleading leading `0` from the hour.